# How to find XAML element by name or key inside XAML page in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I have a custom control that has a `VisualElement` as a property. I want to set this element in XAML referring to some other control (VisualElement) in my XAML page.

**Here's Custom control:**

```cs
public class BlurredImage : Image
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty RootElementProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(RootElement), typeof(VisualElement), typeof(BlurredImage), propertyChanged: RootElementPropertyChanged);
    public VisualElement RootElement { get => (VisualElement)GetValue(RootElementProperty); set => SetValue(RootElementProperty, value); }

    static void RootElementPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        // Do some process
    }
}
```

**Here's my XAML code**

```xml
<StackLayout x:Name="myStackLayout">
   ...
</StackLayout>

<controls:BlurredImage RootElement="{Binding myStackLayout, Source={x:Reference thisPage}}" />
```

I want `BlurredImage`'s `RootElement` as `myStackLayout`. How can it be done?

Comment: there is an example in this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings#bindings-without-a-binding-context) of binding one XAML element to another

Comment: @Jason, I am not getting how to do it, can you provide an answer, or additional details would be much appreciated. How can I set `RootElement="someElement"` in XAML?

Comment: `RootElement="{Binding Source={x:Reference someElement}, Path=.}" `